# Encontrar multiplos de 5 o 3 - Project Euler

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer un problema de esta [página](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1), y me salió de la siguiente forma:

```
public static int metodo() {
        int total = 0; 
        for (int i=1; i<1000; ++i) {
            if (i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0) { total += i; } 
        };
        return total;
    }
```

pero estoy intentado no usar el operador del resto, y obtener los múltiplos multiplicando por 5 o 3 de algúna forma pero todas las veces que no intente no me dio el resultado esperado, hay forma de hacerlo mediante multiplicación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En cierto modo este es un problema más de matemáticas que de programación.

Primero vamos a calcular la suma de los números menores que X que son múltiplos de un divisor D. 
Calculamos el máximo múltiplo de D que es menor que X, lo llamamos M(X,D) :
M(X,D) = ( (X-1) división_entera D ) * D

En el caso del divisor 3 : M(1000,3) = 999

Calculamos la suma : 3 + 6 + ... + 996 + 999 ; a la cual llamamos S(X,D)

Esto es una [progresión aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica), cuya suma viene dada por :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde :

- a1 = D
- an = M(X,D)
- n = M(X,D)/D

Que en java calculamos así :

```
// Calcular S(X,D)
public static int sumaMultiplosMenores( int maximo, int divisor )
{
    int maxMultiplo = ((maximo-1)/divisor)*divisor; // M(X,D)
    int numTerminos = maxMultiplo/divisor;          // n
    return numTerminos*(maxMultiplo+divisor)/2;     // S(X,D)
}
```

El resultado final es las sumas de los múltiplos de 3 y 5 que son menores que X, es decir : S(1000,3)+S(1000,5)

Pero hay un problema, al hacer lo anterior hemos sumado los múltiplos de 15 dos veces, para compensar los restamos una vez : Resultado final = S(1000,3)+S(1000,5)-S(1000,15)

En java esto es :

```
public static int metodo()
{
    return sumaMultiplosMenores(1000, 3) +
           sumaMultiplosMenores(1000, 5) -
           sumaMultiplosMenores(1000, 15); 
}
```

Esta forma requiere un tiempo constante de ejecución, mientras que con un bucle el tiempo aumenta conforme aumenta X.

Comment: Solo como comentario, tener cuidado de que el resultado pueda sobrepasar el valor máximo de un `int`.

Comment: Es un comentario relevante. Es un error que existió durante años en las librerías standard de Java : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6412541 . Pero me temo que sumar enteros es algo demasiado habitual y tener que protegerse de un overflow en TODOS los casos es demasiado costoso. Ese tipo de fallo no creo que deje de aparecer hasta que los overflows causen una excepción, como es el caso de por ejemplo la división por cero. Probablemente la mayoría de las respuestas en SO sobre java que contienen una suma pueden sufrir de este bug.

Comment: *tener que protegerse de un overflow en todos los casos es demasiado costoso* no, no lo es. Pero para efectos prácticos de esta pregunta y el problema de project euler, esto es suficiente.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza . Si no es demasiado costoso, ¿Cómo es que he encontrado ejemplos en que no lo has hecho? Parece que no haces lo que predicas. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12940/crear-un-programa-que-le-permita-ver-cuantos-objetos-se-han-creado-de-una-clase/12943#12943  ,  http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10209/crear-un-tablero-en-java/10292#10292

Answer (score 3):

Una posibilidad:

```
public static int metodo2(int n) {
    int total = 0;
    for( int i = 3; i < n; i += 3 )
        total += i;
    for( int i = 5; i < n; i += 5 )
        total += i;
    for( int i = 15; i < n; i += 15 )
        total -= i;
    return total;
}
```

Explicación: sumamos primero todos los multiplos de 3 y luego los de 5.
Luego restamos los que son múltiplos de ambos (por lo tanto, multiplos de 15)
para corregir el hecho de que estos los hemos sumando por duplicado antes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int metodo(int n) {
    int x=5, y=3;
    int c=0, c1 = 0, c2 =0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i%y == 0){
            c+=i;
        }
        else if(i%x == 0){
            c+=i;
        }

    }
        return c;
}
```

Si haces las comparaciones por separado es mas sencillo, yo también hice esos problemas y este código me dio el resultado correcto.

Comment: Hola @Joaquin. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. No obstante, leyendo la pregunta, el autor pide no usar el operador `%`. ¿Algún motivo por el que lo usaras?